# Can multiple trackers be created with the same tracking ID?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm providing a service on a client's website and they want me to trigger events in Google Analytics related to my software. The site has multiple trackers and I need my events to appear in a specific one, which is already used by the site for standard tracking. At the point where I need to send the events the tracker is already created however I don't know its name. My question is, if I create it again like this:

```
 ga("create", "UA-xxxxxxx-4", "auto", {"name":"mytracker"})
```

,assuming a tracker with tracking ID `UA-xxxxxxx-4` was already created, will "mytracker" just be an alias to the same tracking ID or do I run the risk if preventing the site from sending any further events to `UA-xxxxxxx-4`

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right, you need to send events to specific tracker, and you are going to add name in one of existing trackers.

In case of hardcoded GA by default page views and events will be send to all trackers. If you need to specify tracker, you should name it in this way

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Z', 'auto', 'clientTracker');
```

and use this name every time you send data

```
ga('send', 'pageview'); // For default trackers
ga('clientTracker.send', 'pageview'); // For your tracker
```

So if you assign a name to some existing tracker, you need to update all necessary previously configured events and page view tags for this tracker.